# Do I always have to inject all the dependencies first before using any of its methods in Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm new to Magento 2. In Magento 1, as you know, we can call any method from other class(es) more easily, thanks to Mage::

In Magento 2, I notice every time I want to use a method(s) from other class(es), I have to inject the dependency(ies) first which can make the constructor looks very long with so many injections. I read we can use object manager but it's not preferable. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious advantage for me using dependencies instead of object manager, is that you can leverage it anywhere in your class. Using object manager you have to call the methods for each function individually. It may seem a more practical approach at first, but with more complex code your functions will bloat because you always have to refer to object manager instead of referring to the method directly via dependency. I'd rather have a "big block of construction" on top instead of all these object manager instances in my functions.

Also, it can be quite tricky to use object manager correctly. Maybe have a look at this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Quite tough learning Magento 2 compare with Magento 1.